# Bootstrap main container eclipsed by navbar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, containers, navbar

I'm trying to pilot the bootstrap from the starter page. I hoped everything should go well and the page should be rendered as the starter page shows. But I met a weird issue (as far as I can't figure it out) that the main container can't be placed to the center of the page. In fact, the main container was positioned to the same place as the navbar, as in the screenshot. The same result on both IE & Firefox. And I haven't customized the bootstrap.min.css.

[image: the position of main container in inspection mode]

The source html is as below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="icon" href="../../../../favicon.ico">
    <title>Starter Template for Bootstrap</title>
    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS-->
    <link href="/stylesheets/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Custom styles for this template-->
</head>

<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-dark fixed-top" style="background-color: #124191;">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
            <Google></Google>
        </a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarsExampleDefault" aria-controls="navbarsExampleDefault" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation"><span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span></button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarsExampleDefault">
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Google </a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Google</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Google</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Google</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Google</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Google</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Google</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item dropdown"><a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" id="dropdown01" href="https://example.com" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown</a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdown01"><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <main class="container" role="main">
        <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">Card subtitle</h6>
                <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card&apos;s content.</p><a class="card-link" href="#">Card link</a><a class="card-link" href="#">Another link</a></div>
        </div>
    </main>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="/javascripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

could you please help?

Comment: Kindly check the answer of Rundik , hopefully it will help you. Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add padding to the body so that it's pushed below the nav. Put this in a css file referenced after your bootstrap file

`body { padding-top: 70px; }`

Comment: Thank you, this solves my issue. In fact, the Bootstrap starter example, a customized css was used that I did't notice.  the following was added:

 body {
  padding-top: 5rem;
}

Answer (score 1):

navbar should be in the container like this

```
<main class="container" role="main">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-dark fixed-top" style="background-color: #124191;">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
            <Google></Google>
        </a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarsExampleDefault" aria-controls="navbarsExampleDefault" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation"><span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span></button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarsExampleDefault">
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Google </a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Google</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Google</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Google</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Google</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Google</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Google</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item dropdown"><a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" id="dropdown01" href="https://example.com" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown</a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdown01"><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
        <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
            <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">Card subtitle</h6>
            <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card&apos;s content.</p><a class="card-link" href="#">Card link</a><a class="card-link" href="#">Another link</a></div>
    </div>
</main>
```

Comment: you can also try to set the position of the navbar to static

Comment: could you check https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/examples/starter-template/, in fact I did the same thing as this example, but the result is quite different.

Comment: in this link the body tag has  padding-top of 5rem

Answer (score 0):

Just  add  "navbar-fixed-top" class  to  navbar calss